# Automate shell script which asks for password

Tags: bash, shell, automation

I have a complex shell script which calls various other scripts. Some command inside this scripts prompt for sudo password. I am writing a wrapper script to automate this.
So, with online research I found the below things:

1. Create a sudoer file with no passwords but it seems a list of commands have to be given for which this condition will apply. I don't want to search which command inside the scripts is invoking sudo password prompt because that would take too much time.
2. Expect utility. This works with expect interpreter and i cannot spawn the script because spawn is a expect interpreter command. So, basically the below code works with expect:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/expect
> spawn sudo su
> expect "*assword"
> send "abc12\n"
> interact
> ```

but what I need is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./complex_script.sh <arg1> <arg2>
expect "*assword"
send "abc12\n"
interact
```

When I run this I get the below error:
*couldn't execute "complex_script.sh": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn complex_script.sh rootfs"
    (file "./a.sh" line 2)*

3. echo password | script.sh also does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just start the script as root and forget the sudo commands?

Comment: The error says is not finding the script to spawn. Did you tried using absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine as far as I can see. The error message "no such file or directory" is most likely coming up because of this line using a relative path `spawn ./complex_script.sh <arg1> <arg2>`

Try and use the full path, the script should work as expected.